# Average for column value across multiple datasets in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I need help in this. I have 3 data sets from 3 different years. they have the same columns with different values for each year. I want to find the average for the column values across the three years based on the name field. To be specific:

assume : first data set

```
Name Age Height Weight
A     4    20     20
B     5    22     22
C     8    25     21
D     10   25     23
```

second data set

```
Name Age Height Weight
A     5    22     25
B     6    23     26
```

Third data set

```
Name Age Height Weight
A     6    24     24
B     7    24     27
C     10   27     28
```

I want to find the average height for "A" across the three data sets

Answer (score 0):

We can place them in a `list` and `rbind` them, group by 'Name' and get the `mean` of each column

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3))[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = Name]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>%
          group_by(Name) %>%   
          summarise_each(funs(mean))
```